# Automated ML Scheduled Pipeline Not Triggerring Automatically

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, pipeline, automl

I have 2 pipelines:

1. Uploading data from a blob storage to the datastore (to update the data asset)
2. Training model

I also have 2 schedules:

1. Triggers every 10 minutes to call the pipeline 1
2. Triggers when there is a new data in datastore

I used [this notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/continuous-retraining/auto-ml-continuous-retraining.ipynb) as a starter code and modified it to fit my needs.

Code for Schedule 1

```py
schedule = Schedule.create(
    workspace=ws,
    name="data_ingestion_schedule",
    description="Schedule that updates the Dataset",
    pipeline_parameters={"ds_name": DATASET_NAME},
    pipeline_id=published_pipeline.id,  # id of the published data upload pipeline
    experiment_name=EXPERIMENT_NAME,
    recurrence=ScheduleRecurrence(frequency="Minute", interval=10),
    wait_for_provisioning=True
)
```

Code for Schedule 2

```py
schedule = Schedule.create(
    workspace=ws,
    name="retraining_schedule",
    description="Schedule that triggers training pipeline",
    pipeline_parameters={"ds_name": DATASET_NAME, "model_name": MODEL_NAME},
    pipeline_id=published_pipeline.id,  # id of the published training pipeline
    experiment_name=EXPERIMENT_NAME,
    datastore=dstor,
    path_on_datastore=DATASET_NAME,
    wait_for_provisioning=True,
    polling_interval=5
)
```

So, the problem is that the second schedule does not get triggered even where there is change in data in the datastore (at this path - `dstore/DATASET_NAME`). I waited and tried uploading multiple files, but the second schedule never get triggered.

I have tried it in different workspaces, datastore and path on datastore but did not succeed. I have tried searching on Google but havent found anything.

Ideally, I want to be able to upload new data to a blob storage -> then pipeline 1 (triggered by schedule 1) will take the data from the storage and upload to datastore -> pipeline 2 (triggered by schedule 2) takes the updated dataset and (re-)train the model.

Comment: Is your datastore behind a VNET? If so I don't believe it will work as those are not supported when looking at the Schedule.create documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.schedule.schedule?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-pipeline-core-schedule-schedule-create

Comment: No the datastore is not behind a VNET